Accuracy of the Neural Network changes when saved into and loaded from file
I believe the problem is in the constructor MultNnet(String path, Activation[] activations, Activation[] derivatives)
and/or the method void save(String path). When I calculate the accuracy multiple times in the same instance of the program it doesn't change, only happens when the model is saved and reloaded:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix;

interface Activation {
    double activate(double x);
};

interface Interpretor {
    double interpretor(SimpleMatrix output);
}

public class MultNnet {
    SimpleMatrix[] weights;
    SimpleMatrix[] biases;
    Activation[] activations;
    Activation[] derivatives; // the derivative functions will recieve the output of activation as their input

    private static final double EPSILON = 1e-3;

    public MultNnet(int inputSize, int[] neuronSizes, Activation[] activations, Activation[] derivatives) {
        weights = new SimpleMatrix[neuronSizes.length];
        biases = new SimpleMatrix[neuronSizes.length];
        weights[0] = new SimpleMatrix(neuronSizes[0], inputSize);
        biases[0] = new SimpleMatrix(neuronSizes[0], 1);
        initWeights(weights[0]);
        initWeights(biases[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < weights.length; i++) {
            weights[i] = new SimpleMatrix(neuronSizes[i], neuronSizes[i-1]);
            biases[i] = new SimpleMatrix(neuronSizes[i], 1);
            initWeights(weights[i]);
            initWeights(biases[i]);
        }

        this.activations = activations;
        this.derivatives = derivatives;
    }

    private static void initWeights(SimpleMatrix weights) {
        double limit = Math.sqrt(3.0 / weights.getNumCols());
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.getNumRows(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < weights.getNumCols(); j++)
                weights.set(i, j, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(-limit, limit));
    }

    public void save(String path) {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path))) {
            out.println("LayerNo:" + weights.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
                String line = weights[i].getNumRows() + "," + weights[i].getNumCols() + ":";
                for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].getNumRows(); j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k < weights[i].getNumCols(); k++)
                        line += weights[i].get(j, k) + ",";
                for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].getNumRows(); j++)
                    line += biases[i].get(j, 0) + (j < biases[i].getNumElements() - 1 ? "," : "");
                out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MultNnet(String path, Activation[] activations, Activation[] derivatives) {
        this.activations = activations;
        this.derivatives = derivatives;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            int layerNo = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine().split(":")[1]);
            weights = new SimpleMatrix[layerNo];
            biases = new SimpleMatrix[layerNo];
            for (int i = 0; i < layerNo; i++) {
                String[] line = in.readLine().split(":");
                String[] info = line[0].split(",");
                String[] entries = line[1].split(",");
                weights[i] = new SimpleMatrix(Integer.parseInt(info[0]), Integer.parseInt(info[1]));
                biases[i] = new SimpleMatrix(weights[i].getNumRows(), 1);
                for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].getNumElements(); j++)
                    weights[i].set(j, Double.parseDouble(entries[j]));
                for (int j = 0; j < biases[i].getNumElements(); j++)
                    biases[i].set(j, Double.parseDouble(entries[weights[i].getNumElements()] + j));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SimpleMatrix predict(SimpleMatrix input) {
        SimpleMatrix output = input;
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
            final int fi = i; // needed to use it in lambda expression
            output = weights[fi].mult(output).plus(biases[fi]).elementOp((int j, int k, double x) -> activations[fi].activate(x));
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void train(SimpleMatrix[] inputs, SimpleMatrix[] targets, int epoches, double learningRate) {
        for (int i = 0; i < epoches; i++) {
            SimpleMatrix[] gradients = new SimpleMatrix[weights.length];
            SimpleMatrix[] biasGradients = new SimpleMatrix[biases.length];

            for (int j = 0; j < gradients.length; j++) {
                gradients[j] = new SimpleMatrix(weights[j].getNumRows(), weights[j].getNumCols());
                biasGradients[j] = new SimpleMatrix(biases[j].getNumRows(), 1);
            }

            double[] losses = new double[weights.length];

            SimpleMatrix[] outputs = new SimpleMatrix[weights.length];

            for (int j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                SimpleMatrix input = inputs[j];
            
                for (int k = 0; k < weights.length; k++) {
                    final int fk = k; // needed to use it in lambda expression
                    outputs[k] = weights[k].mult(input).plus(biases[k]).elementOp((int m, int n, double x) -> activations[fk].activate(x));
                    input = outputs[k];
                }

                SimpleMatrix error = outputs[outputs.length - 1].minus(targets[j]);
                for (int k = weights.length - 1; k > 0; k--) {
                    double norm = error.normF();
                    losses[k] += norm * norm;
                    final int fk = k; // needed to use it in lambda expression
                    SimpleMatrix biasDerivative = error.elementMult(outputs[k].elementOp((int m, int n, double x) -> derivatives[fk].activate(x))).scale(2);
                    SimpleMatrix weightDerivative = biasDerivative.mult(outputs[k - 1].transpose());
                    biasGradients[k] = biasGradients[k].plus(biasDerivative.divide(inputs.length));
                    gradients[k] = gradients[k].plus(weightDerivative.divide(inputs.length));
                    error = weights[k].transpose().mult(biasDerivative);
                }

                double norm = error.normF();
                losses[0] += norm * norm;
                SimpleMatrix biasDerivative = error.elementMult(outputs[0].elementOp((int m, int n, double x) -> derivatives[0].activate(x))).scale(2);
                SimpleMatrix weightDerivative = biasDerivative.mult(inputs[j].transpose());
                biasGradients[0] = biasGradients[0].plus(biasDerivative.divide(inputs.length));
                gradients[0] = gradients[0].plus(weightDerivative.divide(inputs.length));
            }


            for (int j = 0; j < weights.length; j++) {
                double gradientNorm = gradients[j].normF();
                double biasGradientNorm = biasGradients[j].normF();
                double coefficient = losses[j] / inputs.length / (gradientNorm * gradientNorm + biasGradientNorm * biasGradientNorm + EPSILON);
                weights[j] = weights[j].minus(gradients[j].scale(coefficient * learningRate));
                biases[j] = biases[j].minus(biasGradients[j].scale(coefficient * learningRate));
            }
        }
    }

    private <T> void shuffle(T[] v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(v.length);
            T tmp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[randomIndex];
            v[randomIndex] = tmp;
        }
    }

    public void stochasticTrain(SimpleMatrix[][] inputBatches, SimpleMatrix[][] outputBatches, int epoches, double learningRate) {
        Integer[] batchIndecies = new Integer[inputBatches.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < batchIndecies.length; i++)
            batchIndecies[i] = i;
        while (epoches-- > 0) {
            shuffle(batchIndecies);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < batchIndecies.length; i++)
                train(inputBatches[batchIndecies[i]], outputBatches[batchIndecies[i]], 1, learningRate);
        }
    }

    public double accuracy(SimpleMatrix[] inputs, SimpleMatrix[] targets, Interpretor interpretor) {
        int correct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            SimpleMatrix prediction = predict(inputs[i]);
            if (interpretor.interpretor(prediction) == interpretor.interpretor(targets[i]))
                correct++;
        }
        return correct * 100.0 / inputs.length;
    }

    public double accuracy(SimpleMatrix[][] inputs, SimpleMatrix[][] targets, Interpretor interpretor) {
        int correct = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < inputs[i].length; j++) {
                SimpleMatrix prediction = predict(inputs[i][j]);
                if (interpretor.interpretor(prediction) == interpretor.interpretor(targets[i][j]))
                    correct++;
            }
        return correct * 100.0 / inputs.length / inputs[0].length;
    }
}


What file format is the file saved as? If it is raw binary then there is no reason why it should be degraded as a result. Converted to decimal numbers all bets are off unless you have quite a few extra guard digits beyond nominal precision. When it is critical to have human readable output and bitwise reproducibility I save in the hexadecimal FP representation %a I don't know what it is in java.
